# Custom Console command creation error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, command-line, console

I am creating console command to input values into the database, there is some argument missing an error. I have gone through several tutorials but to me, the code looks fine. The error is:

> Not enough arguments (missing: "Credit, Amount has been credited").

Here is Console Class:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\AmountFactory;

class AddItem extends Command
{
const INPUT_KEY_ACTION = 'Credit';
const INPUT_KEY_REFERENCE = 'Amount has been credited';
//const INPUT_KEY_AMOUNT = 50;

private $amountFactory;

public function __construct(AmountFactory $amountFactory)
{

  $this->amountFactory = $amountFactory;
  parent::__construct();

}

protected function configure()
{

   $this->setName('example:credit:refund')
   ->addArgument(
    self::INPUT_KEY_ACTION,
    InputArgument::REQUIRED,
    'Action name'
   )->addArgument(
    self::INPUT_KEY_REFERENCE,
    InputArgument::REQUIRED,
    'Action Reference'
   );
   //$this->setDescription('Demo console command');

   parent::configure();
   }
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
  {
   $amount = $this->amountFactory->create();
   $amount->setAction($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_ACTION));
   $amount->setReference($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_REFERENCE));
   //$amount->setAmount($input->getArgument(self::INPUT_KEY_AMOUNT));
   $amount->setIsObjectNew(true);
   $amount->save();
   return Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
 }
 }
```

In di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
   <arguments>
       <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="rhinosCredit" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Console\Command\AddItem</item>
       </argument>
   </arguments>
```

When I uncomment lines for third argument i.e Amount I get error

> The "50" argument does not exist.

Can somebody help to figure out this error? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Argument Names are wrong, they should not be with space. for your case you have used

> const INPUT_KEY_REFERENCE = 'Amount has been credited';

it should be like this

> const INPUT_KEY_REFERENCE = 'amount_has_been_credited';

ALso in command you need to share the agruments

> example:credit:refund ARG1 ARG2

Comment: I updated, still same: Not enough arguments (missing: "credit, amount_has_been_credited").

Comment: Can you please share the command you are trying

Comment: example:credit:refund

Comment: Sorry to ask but where are the arguments in this command it should be like example:credit:refund ARG1 ARG2

Comment: Yes it worked, can you update answer so that I can accept.

Comment: edited, please accept

Answer (score 0):

In your configure() function add your argument AMOUNT for amount :

```
->addArgument(self:: INPUT_KEY_AMOUNT,InputArgument::REQUIRED,'Action Amount');
```

Comment: Yes it is added..I missed it while pasting code here.. including this code these errors use to occur